# Regarding Dispose of Connections in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I need your suggestions on the Below implementation.

I'm using Entity Framework for my ASP.NET WEB API Project

my program Flow is:
Repository->BusinessLayer->Controller

my Context name is: UtmDataContext

In Repositories I'm using code some thing like this:

```
    using (SqlConnection objConnection = new SqlConnection(connstr))
    {
        DbCompiledModel compiledModel = UtmCompiledModel.CreateCompiledDataModel(objConnection, schema);
        using (var dataContext = new UTMDataContext(objConnection, compiledModel, true))
        {
            /*Doing some stuff here*/
        }
    }
```

in the above code
schema is a parameter that comes from the user.

my Project requires to have multi-tenant architecture for entity framework. So I’m Building the model and then feeding it to  the UtmDataContext object.

But, I doubt that, is entity framework really closing my objConnection?

Can you please help me on this?  Please let me know if you need any further information

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using `using` on an object implementing `IDisposable`, the compiler interprets the code as having a try/finally block. The `finally` block calls the `Dispose` method of the object.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx

Comment: Thank you for the link. I hope that, compiledModel (This is an Immutable object) object will also be disposed when objConnection is disposed.

Answer (score 0):

Your SqlConnection will be closed and dispose() called on it as soon as everything inside the     [using{}](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx)    block has executed.